# Check if status bar is already visible on iPhone before loading app

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a specific edge case I'm trying to account for - the situation in which the status bar is already visible before even loading the app. My following code in my AppDelegate does not account for this situation (it only accounts for when the status bar is changed):

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame
{
    self.currentStatusBarFrame = newStatusBarFrame;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Status Bar Frame Change"
             object:self
             userInfo:@{@"current status bar frame": [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newStatusBarFrame]}];

}
```

Does anyone know of a similar function that would check if the status bar is already visible? I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere.

Comment: Do you want it to be visible? You can insure it's not by checking hide status bar in your app's deployment info.

Comment: I want to adjust my view if it *is* visible, but I need an event handler to check if it's already visible

Comment: What do you mean by "before loading app"? You can check hide status bar and it will hide the status bar until your app is loaded. Seems like you don't actually mean before app is loaded, but before my rootViewController's view is on screen.

Comment: Yes exactly @beyowulf thank you for clarifying that, that sounds like a great solution, how would I check hide status bar until my rootViewController's view is on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your project in the file navigator see section deployment info -> see status bar style -> check hide status bar. Or add Status Bar Initially Hide true in your app's plist does the same thing.
[image: deployment screen]

Comment: Just to make sure, if I check "Hide Status Bar" to start with, will it still be able to show the status bar when someone calls you for example? I just want it to default to hidden

Comment: Thank you for the great answer

Comment: The status bar will only be hidden for the launch screen. If you want the status bar gone completely, check requires full screen. And I think the system handles the status bar for the phone call.